# Relation between positive part and expectation of the indicator function times a random variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Is there any relation between

$$E[X\mathbb{1}_{\{X>a\}}]$$ and $$E[X-a]^+$$? the values are equal??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not equal, but somewhat related. The positive part of a random variable $Y$ is by definition $$Y^+:=Y{\mathbb 1}_{\{Y>0\}},$$ so
$$\begin{align}E[X-a]^+&=E\left[(X-a){\mathbb 1}_{\{X-a>0\}}\right]\\
&=E\left[(X-a){\mathbb 1}_{\{X>a\}}\right]\\
&=E\left[X{\mathbb 1}_{\{X>a\}}\right]-E\left[a{\mathbb 1}_{\{X>a\}}\right]\\
&=E\left[X{\mathbb 1}_{\{X>a\}}\right]-aP(X>a).
\end{align}
$$